# Permanently deleting Firefox keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard, shortcut

Is there a way to access the firefox directory where all the keyboard shortcuts are stored? I want to be able to delete all of them, and I don't want to rely on the keyconfig extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the file you are looking for is omni.ja that is a jar file in firfox installation directory.

inside that archive you can find at the path /chrome/toolkit/content/global/ a file named platformHTMLBindings.xml that should contain firefox key bindings, but recent firefox versions may have changed the binding system..

Comment: I had to use /chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/communicator-platform/unix/platformCommunicatorOverlay.dtd to change the CTRL-Q key for quitting to something less obnoxiously close to CTRL-W in seamonkey. (that firefox addon doesn't work on seamonkey).